# control shape Key with bones local distance to specific vector?

Tags: python, bones, drivers, shape-keys

I want to control a shape key with a driver that is controlled by a bone. The bone should have lets call it a "**goalVector**" in its local space for example [0.5,0.5,0.5] from its local [0.0,0.0,0.0] "**rootVector**".

If the distance from the "**rootVector**" to the "**goalVector**" is shortened, the driver should be activated. Just like a distance driver but without a seperate object and with just a distance set from the bones local "**rootVector**".

Is there any way to handle this with expressions?

[image]

Comment: While it's possible to do this with drivers, without an extra object, you need three driven properties, XY and Z, to do it, and so the whole thing gets unwieldy.  You can do it with extra objects-- well, extra bones-- very easily in comparison.  Is there some reason you don't want to make some extra, hidden mechanism bones instead?

Comment: I was already trying this, but I dont get how to get the distance from one bone to the other. Cause either they are in local space so they are each in 0.0.0 or they are in world space and the distance is only really measurable if at least one bone is centered in the worlds 0.0.0 origin.

Comment: If they have the same parent, and the parent is unscaled, world space distance and local space distance is the same thing.  They are not in 0,0,0 in local space if they have been moved-- but it's possible you meant something difference than distance?  Maybe you meant, are they pointing the same way as indicated by the goal vector?  That's not the same thing.

Comment: @Nathan
No its just the distance from position A to B that has to be mapped to a range from 0 to 1 for the shape key. 
Anyways, thank you :) for now I will try it with some distance bones, but perhaps there is a way to do this with values, because if the bone goes farther than the distance bone, the value will also shrink again. Not sure if there is a possible and clean way to go around this.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't sound like what I'd call "local space", so that's going to confuse any answers.  And, yes, moving it in a line through goal will mean that the shapekey reaches distance 0 and then increases distance, but I'm not sure what you'd like to happen instead-- if you're not increasing distance afterwards, you're not using distance.  Maybe you should take a step back and talk about the original problem you're trying to solve, for which you feel this is a solution?